# ruby oauth2 put request returns invalid block type error

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0

I'm able to perform get and post requests fine, but when I try to do a put request with the same format, I get:
Zlib::DataError (invalid block type)

here is the backtrace

```
/Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:357:in `finish': invalid block type (Zlib::DataError)
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:357:in `finish'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:262:in `ensure in inflater'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:262:in `inflater'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:274:in `read_body_0'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:201:in `read_body'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:226:in `body'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:163:in `reading_body'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1412:in `block in transport_request'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `catch'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `transport_request'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1376:in `request'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `block in request'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:39:in `call'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/oauth2-0.9.3/lib/oauth2/client.rb:90:in `request'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/oauth2-0.9.3/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb:107:in `request'
from /Users/psi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/oauth2-0.9.3/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb:128:in `put'
from api_check.rb:50:in `<main>'
```

here is the setup code

```
require 'oauth2'

client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENTID, CLIENTSECRET,
  site: SITE, token_url: TOKENURL)

token = client.client_credentials.get_token

response = token.put(PATH, {body: {params1: PARAM1}})
```

Im using oauth2 version 0.9.3
If there is something wrong with the way I'm doing a request, I have no indication from the error log.
If more info is needed let me know.

Comment: Please add the code and backtrace to the post

Comment: the pastebin links should be working

Comment: This is not how SO works - links are frowned upon, since they can become invalid. Also, people are less likely to go to your links, and more likely to read them when they are in the post. Please add your code to the post.

Comment: done. i didnt know links were frowned upon. i do like pastebin though.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the response - check the server's output

Comment: so I used curl to do the request and it gave me a 409 and a json response. the format of the curl response i used is curl -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X PUT -d params1=params1 url

Comment: http://100pulse.com/http-statuscode/409.jsp

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why oauth just breaks instead of returning the response. Usually the response is returned with the correct status code and body.

Comment: I tried tracing through the whole thing and figured it was more trouble, so I tried a different Faraday adapter, eventmachine works. Now instead of just breaking, it raises the correct OAuth2::Error exception with a detailed message.

Answer (score 0):

If I use a different Faraday adapter like EventMachine, I get the correct OAuth2::Error exception with a detailed message instead of just breaking.
To change the adapter, add the desired adapter to the Gemfile and add this line before calling OAuth2 methods

```
Faraday.default_adapter = :em_http
```